# Why can't I use `w` for `while` in Tcl's interactive mode?

Tags: tcl

Why can't I use `w` for `while` in Tcl's interactive mode? Only `wh` seems to work:

```
info script {}
set tcl_interactive 1
set i 0
wh {$i<10} {puts [incr i]}
```

(See [Ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/el3f4J).)

`w` seems pretty unambiguous among the collection of commands and procs:

```
puts [lsort [concat [info commands] [info procs]]]
```

> after append apply array auto_execok auto_execok auto_import auto_import auto_load auto_load auto_load_index auto_load_index auto_qualify auto_qualify binary break case catch cd chan clock clock close concat continue dict encoding eof error eval exec exit expr fblocked fconfigure fcopy file fileevent flush for foreach format gets glob global if incr info interp join lappend lassign lindex linsert list llength load lrange lrepeat lreplace lreverse lsearch lset lsort namespace open package pid proc puts pwd read regexp regsub rename return scan seek set socket source split string subst switch tclLog tclLog tell time trace unknown unknown unload unset update uplevel upvar variable vwait while

This question, like the other one I just asked, is purely abstract—I noticed this odd behavior while code-golfing and wanted to understand the internals a little better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `w` for `while` because Tcl found a program on your path called `w` (probably `/usr/bin/w` in full) and it favors that exact match over the prefix matching of Tcl commands.

You probably ought to be not *quite* so lazy; `wh` should work. (For now. No promises *at all* that we won't add more commands in the future that end up causing problems.)

```
% info commands w*
while
% w 1 {puts hi;break}
 0:02  up 89 days, 14:58, 12 users, load averages: 0.46 0.62 0.73
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
% auto_execok w
/usr/bin/w
% wh 1 {puts hi;break}
hi
```

Comment: The `auto_execok` is a magical procedure that looks up how to run a named external command (sometimes a non-trivial task). It's documented, of course.

Comment: Ah, that clears up that up. Thank you! (Incidentally this is only for [a match of code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20570/14255)—nothing I'd employ in any practical application.) But it does show significantly that it might be unstable to rely on interactive shortcuts, since it'll depend on programs in the user's path...

Comment: Tcl can't usually get quite as short as Perl in codegolf. Protip: abbreviating subcommands works fine, and you can do evil things with `interp alias`. Or you can go for the jugular and deploy compressed code (with `zlib decompress` in 8.6). ;-)

Comment: Yeah, people actually start to limit my `zlib i` on [codegolf.se].